# waiting for function execution before running other code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function the loads JS files, one of the JS
file is important to the other code to run successfully so i am trying to wait till the function successfully load it.

Till now i have tried several ways- but they didn't work for me, like this one for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function kickOff() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {  
            loadRemoteFile("hconfig.js");       
        });
    }
    kickoff().then(function (result) {
        run the code that depends on the code that kickoff() run
    });
});
```

**LoadRemoteFile function**

```
function loadRemoteFile(filename, loadIntoHeader){ 
        filetype = filename.match(".css") ? "css" : "js";

        if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
            if(!loadIntoHeader){
                var script   = document.createElement("script");
                script.type  = "text/javascript";
                script.src   = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(script);          
            }else{
                var fileref=document.createElement('script');
                fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);              
            } 
        }else if (filetype=="css"){ 
            if(!loadIntoHeader){
                var style   = document.createElement("link");
                style.type  = "text/css";
                style.rel   = "stylesheet";
                style.href   = filename;    
                document.body.appendChild(style);
            }else{          
                var fileref=document.createElement("link");
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
            } 
        }
}
```

Is it a good solution? why isn't it working?

Comment: You need to resolve the `Promise()` you create. Only after that happens will `then()` be executed. To do this you'll most likely need to add a callback to `loadRemoteFile()`

Comment: @Rory , can you show me how to do it?

Comment: What is `loadRemoteFile` doing? That is your own implementation... in general you can do something like this: `jQuery.getScript("hconfig.js", function() { /* your other code */ })`

Comment: i updated the question with the function `"loadRemoteFile"`

Comment: @E.Meir I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call `resolve()` on the `Promise()` you created. Only after that happens will the logic in `then()` be executed.

To do this I'd suggest you restructure your logic so that `loadRemoteFile()` itself returns the promise, that way it's in scope to be resolved without needing to pass it around as an argument. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function kickOff() {
    return loadRemoteFile("hconfig.js");
  }

  function loadRemoteFile(filename) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('loading remote file...');
      
      // your logic here...

      setTimeout(function() { // pretend this is an AJAX request....
        console.log('remote file loaded.');
        resolve(); // resolve the promise here to signify all work has been completed
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  kickOff().then(function(result) {
    console.log('kickoff...');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you can also call `reject()` in the Promise handler if there was an error encountered during the remote call.

Alternatively you could change the logic to use a callback pattern. This negates the need for the Promise and your intermediary `kickOff()` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function loadRemoteFile(filename, cb) {
    console.log('loading remote file...');

    // your logic here...

    setTimeout(function() { // pretend this is an AJAX request....
      console.log('remote file loaded.');
      cb && cb();
    }, 2000);
  }

  loadRemoteFile("hconfig.js", function(result) {
    console.log('kickoff...');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i call the `loadRemoteFile` function from other places also. will i need to change the call from there also?

Comment: If you want to work with the promise it returns, then yes.

Comment: and if don't- i don't have to make any change to the other calls?

Comment: No, but just make sure they still complete as you expect them to, as they are asynchronous.

Comment: what is "cb && cb();" you wrote?

Comment: i need to replace "console.log('kickoff...');" with the code that expect the file to be loaded?

Comment: That's correct. Anything executed at that point can be guaranteed that the file has been loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158331/discussion-between-e-meir-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: I've just noticed your edit to the question, though. It looks like you're trying to dynamically append stylesheets and JS scripts to the DOM after the page has loaded. I'd avoid doing this if at all possible. as it just adds complexity without any large benefit. A better approach is to bundle and minify all your JS in to a single file (and the same in a separate file for your CSS) and include them once.

Comment: i am in the chat.. about the "bundle and minify" i am doing it- but you dont see it in the code that i published- the end-user can choose if he wants to bundle it all to one file.. if he check a checkbox

Comment: if you will look at the function "loadRemoteFile" that i published- it has a second parmeter "loadIntoHeader", but you pass it a function- why? it is not working for me that way

Comment: You added that code after I updated this question. The point there is that you need to add an extra parameter to the function.

Comment: the callback solution didn't worked for me- the code executed even though the file didn't load. i am trying one the promise solution.

Comment: Then you have made a mistake somewhere in your implementation. I'd suggest starting a new question about it